# how to load xml in imageview using glide

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I have created an gradient `xml` in drawable folder of my project. I want to load that `xml` in an `ImageView` using `Glide`. How can I do that ?

Simple loading of image in ImageView using Glide:

```
Glide.with(LoginActivity.this).load(R.drawable.a270).asBitmap().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT).into(backgroundImage);
```

But if I use the same code above replacing `R.drawable.a270` with `R.drawable.gradient_background` with a drawable xml its not working.

Comment: you can use it directly know ? why you need to use it via Glide ??

Comment: Because the `gradient_background.xml` will have a bitmap as well which is of 1920x1200 dimension.

Comment: anyway, you can use directly the xml drawable ? can you post your xml ?

Comment: @Hiren Is your drawable static or animated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this -

```
Glide.with(LoginActivity.this).load("").error(R.drawable.gradient_background).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT).into(backgroundImage);
```

OR

```
Glide.with(LoginActivity.this).load(null).fallback(R.drawable.gradient_background).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT).into(backgroundImage);
```

I doubt you are using `VectorDrawable` or animated `drawable`. Please refer [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1532) and [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1261) for more information on this.

Comment: which version of Glide are you using ? `null` cannot be used as an argument type for `load()` method

Comment: @Hiren I used glide sometime back. Can't remember the version I used. I went back to the discussion in the links I have attached. Thanks for the edit  :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)